# ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, macos, linker

**Either the PEBKAC or MAC is really dumb. I have the following code.**

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Parser.h"

using namespace std;

const char *filename = "main.c";

int main()
{
    cout<<"Parser"<<endl;

    Parser *p = new Parser(filename);
    p->parse();

   return 0;
 }
```

Parser.h

---

```
#ifndef PARSER_H
#define PARSER_H

struct Parser
{
  Parser(const char* filename_);
  bool parse();

  private:
   const char* filename;
};

Parser::Parser(const char* filename_):filename(filename_){}

#endif
```

### Parser.cpp

```
#include "Parser.h"

#include <iostream>

bool Parser::parse()
{
  std::cout<<"The file name is "<<filename<<std::endl;
  return false;
}
```

I get this following error when I try to compile using command

g++ Parser.cpp main.cpp

duplicate symbol __ZN6ParserC2EPKc in:
       /var/folders/sh/3w74dm6n05jbtbv6hzx9f3_00000gn/T/Parser-7ddc8e.o
       /var/folders/sh/3w74dm6n05jbtbv6hzx9f3_00000gn/T/main-90a53f.o
   duplicate symbol __ZN6ParserC1EPKc in:
       /var/folders/sh/3w74dm6n05jbtbv6hzx9f3_00000gn/T/Parser-7ddc8e.o
       /var/folders/sh/3w74dm6n05jbtbv6hzx9f3_00000gn/T/main-90a53f.o
    ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see     invocation)

**When I remove ' "#include "Parser.h" ' from Parser.cpp, this error disappears (If I do that I cannot define any functions in Parser.cpp file). Isnt guarding the whole point of avoiding duplicate symbols? Not sure why it wont work in MAC? (I am using MAC console btw). Tried so many threads, no answer is clear. Sorry if it is a duplicate**

Answer (score 1):

MAC: 1 Me:0

Found out the answer, not sure why I was defining the constructor outside the class in Parser.h file. Either I should have defined it inside the class or outside in .cpp file. This article helped me to understand what I was doing wrong.

http://samwho.co.uk/blog/2013/12/08/duplicate-symbol-what/

### Parser.h

struct Parser
    {
      Parser(const char* filename_);
      bool parse();

```
  private:
  const char* filename;
 };

Parser::Parser(const char* filename_):filename(filename_){} <-- This is the problem, has to be either defined inside the class or outside in .cpp.
```

***THIS FIXED IT.*** (should write code in C++ more often). I guess I wont delete the thread, I have a feeling someone will need it. Couldn't find many resources for g++. (Not many people using g++ in MAC I suppose)

### Parser.h

```
struct Parser
{
  Parser(const char* filename_): filename(filename_){}
  bool parse();

  private:
  const char* filename;
 };
```